# Unable to launch EC2 instance even after deleting CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I just figured out about `AWS CloudWatch` that would let you terminate your EC2 instance after some time in inactivity. So I created an alarm that would terminate the instance when the CPU usage is less the 1% for 2 hours.  Which ultimately ended up putting my instance into an alarm state right away and it prevented me from starting it up to test the feature out.

I then deleted the CloudWatch alarm again in order to be able to launch the EC2 instance gain but even after I deleted the CloudWatch, the state is set to Terminated but the but the Start option from the Actions drop down button is still disabled.

How do I get the instance to start again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restart a terminated instance. The instance no longer exists. It is just listed as "terminated" in your web console for a little bit so you can see that it was deleted. You have to create a new instance now.

Comment: What, any way that I can get that instance restored? I didnt delete the instance, what happened? :o

Comment: Terminating an instance deletes it forever. If you didn't want that you should have "stopped" the instance instead of terminating it. It's gone now. If it was important you should have at least been making EBS or AMI snapshots of it.